# IMAP traffic bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth, isa-server

I want to find out how much of my bandwidth is related to email downloads.

We use Google Apps for our email and have around 60 iMAC users donwloading email via IMAP.  Our firewall is an ISA Server 2006 server.

I just installed GFI Webmonitor, but it only tracks web usage and not secureNat clients which is used for other protocols like IMAP and SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall should be able to tell you that.  I used to use SonicWALL with SonicView and it did nice job in reporting.  I can't remember, however, if it broke it down by user or just totals.  Hope it helps.

Comment: The reports provided by ISA Server are too simple and everything is aggregated.  I know the data is in the logs, but I need a tool to get to it easily.